# Windows 2008 R2 DNS cant resolve own SOA

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, nslookup

We have two Domain Controllers for our network. They both run DHCP, DNS, and ADS. They are both VM's sitting on MS Hyper V Server 2008 on separate physical hosts. We had our primary DC go down a week ago. I upgraded an already existing VM to Primary DC and built a new VM for the secondary. Both DNS servers are running and the SOA is configured correctly for Primary DC 1. However when I run the best practice analyzer it states the server cannot resolve it's own SOA. Check the configuration in the adapter. I checked and they are configured properly. I also went through the DNS entries thoroughly and made sure there was no records of the previous DC that went down. NSLOOKUP resolves the domain and primary dc fine. I also checked the firewalls on the machines and our physical firewall for any deny packets. Any suggestions? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the follwoing commands on each of your domain controllers.

repadmin /showrepl

dcdiag /v

The output of these commands should give you an indication of where the problem might potentilly be.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The only in running dcdiag /v is a replication issue, only because the rules most likely are not defined. Everything else passes.